# Bootstrap carousel content needs to be an output of html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How to display the output of a html page into my bootstrap carousel instead of displaying images? I'd tried creating a div and used css to supply the contents to that ac1_div using `content:url(carousel_content.html)`. It doesn't work.

```
<!-- our global achievers carousel -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active" id="ac1_div">

        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="../images/banner_carousel_b.jpg" alt="...">

        </div>
         <div class="item">
          <img src="../images/banner_carousel_c.jpg" alt="...">

        </div>

      </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
</div>

            </div>
        </div>

/*my css code*/

    #ac1_div
        {
            content: url("../pages/achievers/ac1.html");
            }
<!--ac1.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>achiever</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY to Create a container and put the carousel inside it Code

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
      <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <a><img src="../image/yourimage.png" /></a>

          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```